# Exporting specific data from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to find a macro that will look for specific column(s) in a pretty big Excel file and export/copy them each to a new Microsoft Word file.

For instance, say I want columns `H`, `I`, `J`, and `O` from an Excel file, each with their own Microsoft Word document (hopefully with the document named as the first cell data of each column).

I usually work with Microsoft Word macros, but Excel seems a bit more tricky.

Comment: `I'm trying to find a macro that will look for specific column(s)` This a wrong place to find :) Try Google. If you want help with some specific code then we can definitely help. For that you will have to show us what you tried :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to write the macro, you will need to use the Reference `Microsoft Word x.x Object Library`. Then you can use the `Word.Application` type to control Word.

For instance, this would open and close an instance of Word:

```
Dim w As Word.Application
Set w = CreateObject("Word.Application")
w.Visible = True ' if you want the user to see the window
w.Quit
```

To access the data from the cells in the columns you want, you need to use the `Worksheet.Cells` table. For example, to read the H column (H is the 8th column):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String
i = 1

Do
    s = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8)
    If s = "" Then Exit Do
    MsgBox s
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

I believe you can start from here.